# Finding Jordan Basis of a nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, nilpotence

I have to find the basis of the nilpotent matrix $A$ of size $3\times3$.
$$
\left(\begin{matrix} 1&1&1\\-1&-1&-1\\1&1&0\end{matrix}\right) 
$$

I found that

- $A^3=0$
- $ker A^0={0}$
- $ker A^1=Span \left(\begin{matrix} -1\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right)$
- $ker A^2=Span \left(\begin{matrix} 0\\0\\1\end{matrix},\begin{matrix} -1\\1\\0\end{matrix} \right)$

I don't know how to work from here, can you please show me how to use the algorithm for finding the Jordan basis of a nilpotent matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like this order: you know the minimal polynomial is $\lambda^3.$ So, first you choose (it makes no genuine difference) your favorite column vector $w$ such that 
$$ A^2 w \neq 0.   $$
Once that choice is made, everything else is forced. We calculate
$$ v = Aw,  $$
$$  u = a v $$
Then the change of basis matrix $R$  that goes on the right will have columns, in order, $(u,v,w)$
I like
$$
w =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
then we get

$$
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&1 \\
-1&-1&0 \\
0&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and
$$
R^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&-1&-1 \\
0&0&1 \\
1&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&-1&-1 \\
0&0&1 \\
1&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&1 \\
-1&-1&-1 \\
1&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&1 \\
-1&-1&0 \\
0&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0 \\
0&0&1 \\
0&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and the order we actually use for calculating things

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&1 \\
-1&-1&0 \\
0&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0 \\
0&0&1 \\
0&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&-1&-1 \\
0&0&1 \\
1&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&1 \\
-1&-1&-1 \\
1&1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

There is going to be one chain of vectors belonging to the Eigenvalue 0. For the first vector pick anything from $$Ker^{1}$$ and then try to find a vector in Im A that is projected on your first chosen vector and then repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

- find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors
- determine the Jordan canonical form $J$ for $A$
- from the condition $AP=PJ$ find the Jordan basis(i.e. column vectors of P)

Answer (score 0):

You have a true eigenvector to eigenvalue $0$: $v_1 = [1,-1,0]^T$.

Which vector maps onto it? $A^{-1}v_1$ does maybe you found it $v_2=[0,0,1]^{T}$

Now which maps on that one? (**Hint**: will be same procedure)